# How do I use xmllint in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, xmllint, sublimelinter

I recently installed SublimeLinter in Sublime Text 3 to help me write my JavaScript files correctly.  I also setup xmllint to help me with XML files I work with.  However I cannot get it to run in Sublime Text 3.  I followed [these steps](http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2011/10/08/3-steps-to-download-xmllint/) to get it installed and running, I can list its directory from the command prompt and everything is in order.  Xmllint is also enabled in Sublime Text 3.  However when I work with an XML file in Sublime Text 3 the linter does not appear to be working.  How can I configure xmllint so that it will run within Sublime Text 3?

Comment: What syntax are you using with the xml file? Also, does the debug console tell you that sublimelinter-xmllint is activated?

Comment: not sure how to locate the syntax of my xml file.  Sublime text 3 does say that xmllint is enabled. Is that the debug console?

Comment: fyi: you can see the syntax in the right bottom corner of sublime. you can click on it to change the syntax if needed. this is the thing that also effects the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer [here](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#debugging-path-problems) in the info snippet at the bottom:

> On Windows, linter errors messages will not always appear. It appears
>   to be a bug in python.

And below:

> Unlike the other error messages mentioned earlier, you would not see
>   this message unless debug mode was turned on, because it isn’t an
>   error message detected by SublimeLinter, it is the output captured
>   from the [...] executable. So if you aren’t seeing any errors or
>   warnings in the console and the linter isn’t working, turn on debug
>   mode to see if you can find the source of the problem.